# rails is not found when trying to start a new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, aptana

I just installed Eclipse, then Ruby 1.9.2 then RailsInstaller. I then installed Aptana plugin for eclipse.

My directory setup are as follows:

```
C:\Ruby192
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.8.7
```

When I create a new rails project in Eclipse, It throws this error:

```
LOL@LOL-PC /d/Projects/rail 
$ rails .
sh.exe": rails: command not found
```

I found this [solution](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=2333), but it seems its for linux. I'm using Windows 7.

I reinstalled rails and ruby but its the same thing. I also had installed GitBash and GitExtensions a few months ago and had this problem. I solved it by pointing to the directory where Git was and setting the Default environment to `HOME`.

I now have no idea what to do to use ruby on rails in this error.

Comment: You should modify the question title "rails is not found..." since this is the error reported (sh is the exe reporting the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the place where you installed rails to your PATH environment variable. (Presumably C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rails*\bin)

I also noticed you are using the RailsInstaller for ruby 1.8.7 but seem to have installed ruby 1.9.2. This may cause trouble in the future.

Try following [this](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/getting-started/installation/windows) guide for installing rails on windows. It uses gem install instead of the out dated RailsInstaller.

Comment: there is no gems folder in C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rails*\bin)

Comment: Where on your system is the rails gem installed. It may not be installed using rubygems, if it is `gem which rails` should tell you.

Comment: You need to add C:\RubyXXX\bin to your path. This sorted it for me. Obviously replace XXX with appropriate version number. Mine is 193.